# static keyword on a function call

Tags: c

About the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int lastval(void) 
{ 
   `static int k = 0; 
    return k++; 
}

int main(void)
{

   int i = 0;

   printf("I previously said %d\n", lastval());
   i++;
   i++;
   i++;
   i++;
   i++;
   printf("I previously said %d\n", lastval());
   i++;
   i++;
   i++;
   printf("I previously said %d\n", lastval());
   i++;
   i++;
   i++;
   printf("I previously said %d", lastval());
   i++;
   i++;
   i++;

   return 0;

}
```

can anyone explain to me how does static maintain its value ? I though it was because the stack frame for the function wasnt destroyed after the return so I wrote this code to run it under gdb and I after doing backtraces after every single line only main's stack frame show up (it doesnt even list lastval when I do a backtrace sitting on a printf call, but anyway).

How its k actually stored ? I know that's not like a normal variable since the first k++ returns 1 instead of 0, and its not like a global since i cant access k inside main for example, so .. what's going on ?

`on a local k,  K++ // Always returns 0

`on a global k = 0, k++ // returns 0, 1, 2

`on a static k, k++ // returns 1, 2 ,3

Can anyone help me to understand these 2 issues ?

Comment: Please remove those `i++;` It is not doing anything in your code.

Comment: I copied it as it was, since I was going to add null statements but didnt knew if gdb would just skip them, those i++ are there only to have time to backtrace and see if the stackframe for lastval was still there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A static definition inside a function is just like a static definition outside a function other than the scope of the symbol (where in your the program you can refer to it). It has nothing to do with stack frames ... k isn't on the stack, it's in "static"/global/.data memory.

> I know that's not like a normal variable since the first k++ returns 1 instead of 0

No, it returns 0, but k's value is then 1.

> on a static k, k++ // returns 1, 2 ,3

No, that's not correct ... it returns 0, 1, 2 ...

> and its not like a global since i cant access k inside main for example

That's simply how name scopes work; it has nothing to do with how k is stored.

Comment: Thank you, it does some sense to me.

But, I am not guessing what those return values are, I actually get "I previously said 1" "I previously said 2" and "I previously said 3"

Comment: @SJPRO You may have missed the first output somehow. It simply isn't possible that the first value printed would be 1. Note that you print 4 values, so it would have had to have been 1 ... 2 ... 3 ... 4.

Comment: @JimBalter I previously said 1 I previously said 2 I previously said 3 I previously said 4sebastian@appliance (~): ./statics Yes, I missed the last one in all this confusion, it does say 1,2,3,4. But you know, earlier I tried with ++k but then I changed it, it could be that make didnt compile it even if it seemed it did (possible, happened to me a few times).

Comment: @SJPRO Well, that explains it. I've had a very long programming career but even to this day I sometimes get the results from a previous version of my program ... this can be the tools, but is usually user error.

Answer (score 1):

Not to be snarky, but *any* reference on C will explain this.

The **static** keyword used on a variable within a function allows the value to persist across function calls. It's stored like a global, but you can only access it by name within the scope of the function where it is defined.

Some typical uses of `static` variables in the standard C library occur in the implementations of `rand(3)` and `strtok(3)`. Their use is commonly discouraged because it can lead to functions that are not *reentrant* and thus play havoc when multiple threads are used. POSIX defines a `strtok_r` function for use when reentrancy is required.

Comment: The question was about "how".

Comment: Sorry, I apologize for forcing you to click on my question, read it and answer it. So, thanks !

Comment: I investigated the closing options, but there's no "general reference" option. Learning to use a reference manual is a valuable skill. Believe it or not, I **am** trying to be helpful. Encouraging you to consult a reference work is (IMO) the most helpful advice I can give.

Comment: @SJPRO I often close this sort of question by reason of lack of minimal understanding (a standard reason to close). You are expected to learn the subject before coming to SO and asking questions. Rather than trying to work out everything in gdb (but I don't want to discourage using gdb or experimenting!), you should in this case have read C references and tutorials that explain how the static storage specifier and name scopes work.

Comment: @JimBalter I did, but sorry, I wont ask again. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @SJPRO Please ask questions that you think you should be asking. We're trying to explain our perspective, but you need to do what's best for you.

Comment: @SJPRO I second what Jim Balter says. Please continue to ask questions. If you had added something like "I checked ... and ... and didn't find the answer", I would've had nothing to complain about. Please don't go away mad. That's not what I want at all.

Answer (score 1):

variable `k` is defined inside function `lastval` so its scope is in this function only.But since you defined it with `static` keyword, its lifetime becomes equal to lifetime of programme.

so as per definition of static this variable `k` will be initialized only once and it will retain its last value and that is what happening in your case.Initialized static variable will go in `.data` section of memory.so `k` will get memory in `.data`.

Answer (score 1):

The static variables stored as globals, except their scope. Your program outputs 0 1 2 3 on my computer, so double-check it.

Answer (score 0):

The static variables are instantiated in the global memory space (Not in a stack frame) before the program start executing the main.

C,
That variable is initialized before the program start executing the main.

C++, 
That variable is initialized when the program encounters this line for the 1st time.

When you execute the "lastval()" function, that "static int k = 0" will not be executed again.

Comment: Value assignment will happen on first call of this function, not before program starts.

Comment: No... You're wrong again. The space for static variables are created on compilation, with other global variables. When you call function at first, static variables will get initialized. On the next calls, initialization is not performed. Even if it depends on other data (static int k = 2*n;) initialization performed only once.

Comment: @rasen Both DPG and you are incorrect. From the C standard: "All objects with static storage duration shall be initialized (set to their
initial values) before program startup".

Comment: @JimBalter, okay. But in case of `static int k = 2*n;` first value depends on another variable, so `k` could not be initialized before program startup. So, it initialized on first function call.

Comment: @rasen No, that's not legal C. Do you think the C standard is *lying* when it says that **all** object with static storage duration shall be initialized before program startup? "All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals." Sheesh.

Comment: " With the static keyword, the variable is allocated when the program starts and released when the program ends" .. for those who think that Wikipedia is more reliable than the Standard haha ..

Comment: @JimBalter, Thank you. I was wrong. I was confused by C++ behaviour. But C doesn't allow to initialize static variables with non-constant values.

Comment: @SJPRO No one thinks that, but Wikipedia is essentially correct.

Comment: And the compiler says
"initializer element is not a compile-time constant"
at static int k = n;

So .. well, that's it for me, bye

Comment: @SJPRO, allocation time is same in both C and C++, but initialization time is not. Here was the catch.

Comment: @rasen Dont tell me, I know nothing, not questioning you, just trying those things not to confuse me and posting it only for other noobs like me who might read the stuff at the beggining and get confused too.
Regards.